# Extract characters after the last appearance of a certain symbol in a vector

Tags: r

I have a number of strings like

```
x <- c("1.22.33.444","11.22.333.4","1e.3e.3444.45", "g.78.in.89")
```

i would like to extract only those characters/digits appearing after the last ".". As far as i have looked through the data, there are exactly 4 segments in each of those strings, each separated by a ".", so three "." in each string.

Desired outcome

```
> x
[1] "444" "4"   "45"  "89"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution, using `stringr::str_extract`:

- `$` means the end of the string.
- `\\d+` means one or more numeric digit.
- `(?<=\\.)` looks behind, to check whether behind the numeric digit there is a dot.

You can learn more at: [Lookahead and lookbehind regex tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```r
library(stringr)

x <- c("1.22.33.444","11.22.333.4","1e.3e.3444.45", "g.78.in.89")

str_extract(x, "(?<=\\.)\\d+$")

#> [1] "444" "4"   "45"  "89"
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind explaining what the arguments do? for those not well familiar with regular expressions. Of course, i am not asking for a full lesson, but for example where one could find the information about the last "." in each string.

Comment: Please, see the explanation I have just added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `trimws` from `base R`

```
 trimws(x, whitespace = ".*\\.")
[1] "444" "4"   "45"  "89"
```